# I dont want assetic to oneline my javascript in dev

Tags: javascript, symfony, assetic

I am using Assetic with a symfony2 application which mostly works fine.
One thing that is bugging me though is that in the dev enviroment (app_dev.php) assetic onelines my javascript files. This is a pain in the ass to debug. (Guess what : the error is on line 1 ... duhh )

Is there a way to tell Assetic not to oneline the js files in the dev enviroment ?

For the moment I have : (config.yml)

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
   # java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        # closure:
        #     jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/compiler.jar
        yui_css:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
        yui_js:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
```

And in config_dev.yml :

```
assetic:
    use_controller: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable minification in debug mode. See this document for more info:

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/assetic/yuicompressor.html#disable-minification-in-debug-mode